# PHPMailer not sending email with custom body

Tags: php

i need to send an email with PHPMailer, when trying to get the form elements, fails to send it, but if I use the sample code, it works perfectly.

Also, php sends no error, so the code is executed correctly, I don't understand why this happens.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Obtener datos
try {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$cellphone = $_POST['cellphone'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$colony = $_POST['colony'];
$rfc = $_POST['rfc'];


//Luego tenemos que iniciar la validación por SMTP:
// $mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "krishna.hosting-mexico.net"; 
$mail->Username = "registros@aliar.svri.org.mx"; . 
$mail->Password = "xxxx"; 
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->From = "registros@aliar.svri.org.mx"; 
$mail->FromName = "Registros Aliar"; 
$mail->AddAddress("mauricioandres288@gmail.com");


//Content
    // $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    // $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    // $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    // $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    // $mail->send();

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // El correo se envía como HTML 
    $mail->Subject = "Nuevo registro de"  . $name . " " . $lastName; // Este es el titulo del email. 
    $mail->Body    = "Nuevo registro de"  . $name . " " . $lastName;
    $mail->Body   .= "<br><h4>Datos personales: </h4>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<ul><li>" . $name . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $lastName . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $email . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $speciality . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $title . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $phone . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $adress . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $phone . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $cellphone . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $state . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $colony . "</li>";
    $mail->Body   .= "<li>" . $rfc . "</li></ul>";
    // $mail->Body = $body;

    $mail->send();
 }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Also, I have to mention that my form is in a different php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this and see if it works.

```
<?php 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Obtener datos
try {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$speciality = $_POST['speciality'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$cellphone = $_POST['cellphone'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$colony = $_POST['colony'];
$rfc = $_POST['rfc'];


//Luego tenemos que iniciar la validación por SMTP:
// $mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "krishna.hosting-mexico.net"; 
$mail->Username = "registros@aliar.svri.org.mx"; . 
$mail->Password = "xxxx"; 
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->From = "registros@aliar.svri.org.mx"; 
$mail->FromName = "Registros Aliar"; 
$mail->AddAddress("mauricioandres288@gmail.com");


//Content
    // $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    // $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    // $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    // $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    // $mail->send();

    $mail->IsHTML(true); // El correo se envía como HTML 
    $mail->Subject = "Nuevo registro de"  . $name . " " . $lastName; // Este es el titulo del email. 

    $body="";

    $body .= "Nuevo registro de"  . $name . " " . $lastName;
    $body .=  "<br><h4>Datos personales: </h4>";
    $body .=  "<ul><li>" . $name . "</li>";
    $body .=  "<li>" . $lastName . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $email . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $speciality . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $title . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $phone . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $adress . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $phone . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $cellphone . "</li>";
    $$body .= "<li>" . $state . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $colony . "</li>";
    $body .= "<li>" . $rfc . "</li></ul>";

    $mail->Body = $body;

    $mail->send();
 }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

Comment: To enable debug, use $mail->SMTPDebug = 3.

Comment: Ok...weird, it took 5 minutes for the email to be send...It works now, thanks